# Tag: "apple" or "apple2"? "apple2gs" or "appleiigs"?

Tags: discussion, tags

It's early, but we already have both "apple" and "apple2" tags.  My thought is we should use "apple2" for anything related to Apple II, as the old 128K Macs are very much retro.

I'm not convinced we need to subdivide into separate tags for Apple ][+ vs. Apple //e, but the Apple IIgs was a very different system.  Since that's generally written with "II" rather than "][" or "//", I think "appleiigs" makes sense as a tag.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The way tags have been traditionally used on other sites (including this meta) is to have a hyphen:

[apple-ii](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii) for questions about the Apple II

[apple-iigs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-iigs) for questions about the Apple IIgs

[apple](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) for questions about Apple, the company (not sure if on-topic)

This allows searching for tags in a clear manner, with wildcards. For example [this search for `[apple-*]`](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-*) looks for all apple products. If we used [apple2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple2), as suggested in another answer, the corresponding search would be for `[apple*]` which would include [apple2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple2) but also [apples](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apples), [appleton](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/appleton), etc.

See also [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed), [status-deferred](/questions/tagged/status-deferred), etc. for more examples on this standard.

Comment: I'm leaning this way now too. Thanks for the search tip.

Comment: Hmm, iigs passes the [Google test](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18878/how-do-i-correctly-tag-my-questions).

Comment: Should also be [apple-macintosh] rather than [macintosh]. I've updated a couple of questions, but arguably the Macintosh line is broad enough that [macintosh] is worthwhile as a root. I've also seen [emac] (educational Mac), but I wasn't sure if we want to go hierarchical (apple-macintosh-emac) or keep it brief (apple-emac) or use [macintosh] as the root (macintosh-emac) for ease of search.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the convention for lower-case tags, i or ii or iigs doesn't look great and isn't intuitive.

The most concise and readable tags are: apple1, apple2, apple3 and apple2gs.

Besides, there is a precedent for [apple2gs](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple2gs).

---

UPDATE: Here are sample tags.

[commodore-64](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/commodore-64) [amiga-500](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/amiga-500) [zx-spectrum](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zx-spectrum) [pdp-6](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pdp-6) (used now)

[apple1](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple1) [apple2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple2) [apple3](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple3) [apple2gs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple2gs) (my original preference)

[apple-1](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-1) [apple-2](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-2) [apple-3](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-3) [apple-2gs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-2gs) (with hyphens)

[apple-i](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-i) [apple-ii](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-ii) [apple-iii](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-iii) [apple-iigs](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple-iigs) (these are more consistent - [vote here](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/a/37/71))

Comment: I think [apple2] is widely used in the Apple II community (e.g. the venerable comp.sys.apple2), and I would very much prefer that. I happen to like [appleiigs] more than [apple2gs], but I would bow to the hobgoblins of consistency.

Comment: The normal convention for multi-word tags is with a hyphen: [tag:apple-1], [tag:apple-2gs], etc. With just a number, the hyphen can be omitted, but something like [tag:appleiigs] isreallynotreadable.

Comment: @Gilles So should it be [c64] or [c-64]? Does hyphenation only kick on on full words, e.g. [commodore-64]? I think stranding the poor numeral after a hyphen, as in [apple-2], looks a bit funny. With respect to non-readability, I will note that http://appleiigs.com/ is a perfectly nice domain, which I may or may not be the owner of. :-)  I will concede that [apple2gs] is more readable than [appleiigs], especially for anyone Not Of The Body.

Comment: @fadden I think it should be [tag:commodore-64]. Avoid abbreviations in tags.

Comment: Some great points here. We should aim for consistency. I notice SO has [c64](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c64) but also [commodore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/commodore). It would be nice to get an opinion from a C64 fan.

Comment: With a view to the future, A3000 will mean different things to Commodore Amiga and Acorn Archimedes users. ; - )

Comment: I would very much prefer [tag:apple2], [tag:apple2gs], and such, with [tag:apple] reserved for talk about the company itself (and therefore probably largely off-topic for this area).

Comment: Looking at the other tags in use now (e.g. apple-lisa) I think consistency is going to be better with hyphens. Leaning that way now just leaves the problem of apple-ii vs apple-2, with the former being closer to the way it's actually written despite the wrong case.

Comment: Don't forget the Apple ///!

Comment: My personal preference is apple-ii, apple-digs, apple-iii. This matched the logo and usage in Apple's literature a lot better.

Answer (score -5):

The tag "apple" should be reserved for the (very rare) questions about the original [Apple I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I).

Computers in the Apple II series are largely interchangeable, so a single "appleii" tag (with "apple2" as a synonym) will cover things.

The Apple IIGS was a very different creature, so giving it a dedicated "appleiigs" tag makes sense.

Comment: [tag:apple] would apply to anything manufactured by Apple, not just to the first product they made.

Answer (score -5):

We should use the [apple](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/apple) for questions relating to Apple machines and use the printed, production spelling of the product for each individual product.

Whether II means 2 or not, they chose to print it as Apple II, and we should stick with that.

Comment: Are you suggesting that Apple II questions should have both [apple] and [appleii]? That seems redundant. I'm not sure a generic [apple] tag is useful.

Comment: A generic [tag:apple] tag is not useful. What do the Apple Netwon and the Apple II have in common?