# Manufacturer tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I just posted this question:

[How can I open an IBM G50 CRT monitor?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1379/how-can-i-open-an-ibm-g50-crt-monitor)

and tagged it with IBM, as personally I think there may be people out there who have expertise with particular brands and may want to follow them. Thraka posited that such tags may be useful [in this question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69/tag-macintosh-or-apple-macintosh-amiga-or-commodore-amiga) but I wanted to ask specifically about the use of vendor names (i.e. not models etc.) here. Do we think these are useful/wanted?

Comment: While it may not be the case here due to the differing scope, note that Super User has been in the process of  [removing Manufacturer/Company tags](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/8402/manufacturer-company-tags-are-back-again) as they do not represent a single area of expertise (unlike specific product tags like [microsoft-word]). Just thought I'd raise it so others are aware, RetroC might wanna run things differently :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that these have proven useful, largely for tagging questions about uncommon hardware by these manufacturers that don't have their own tags. In future we may want to use hardware-specific tags instead of manufacturer tags, but these questions already being tagged with manufacturer tags will make it easier to re-tag when more questions about these machines are more popular.

Answer (score 1):

This should be tagged [crt-monitor](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/crt-monitor) (which it is). Even someone not familiar with that particular monitor is not unlikely to have useful information about how to open it because there are common techniques for building CRT monitors and monitors are often made by other manufacturers and rebranded. People watching that tag are likely to want to see this question.

This should not be tagged [ibm](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ibm), nor should we even have that tag, as per the Super User arguments [to remove company/manufacturer tags](https://meta.superuser.com/q/8402/26274):

- That tag is extremely broad and gives very little useful information about the question.
- Such broad tags are kind of pointless to follow, since it's not an area of expertise.
- A search for `[crt-monitor] ibm` produces much better results than a search for `[crt-monitor] [ibm]`.