# Do we need the Interfaces tag?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag

We have recently gained the tag [interfaces](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces).  This  appears to be just a meta-tag with its current usage.

There is just [one question](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4457/276) tagged with it at the moment, which is more concerned with backup.

It would make more sense that interfacing questions use a tag specific to the type of interface concerned.

I would suggest that we abolish [interfaces](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces), any dissension?

Comment: I beg to differ - the question is entitled [What interface did Video Backup System use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4457/278) which isn't as concerned with backup as the interface. Otherwise, it would be tagged with [tag:backup].

Answer (score 3):

I am all for abolishing meta tags, *but*... it's not a meta tag.

[Manufacturer tags](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/232/278) are currently being used for tagging questions about machines that are obscure enough to not have their own tags. The [interfaces](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces) tag could be used in a similar way - for questions about obscure interfaces that do not have their own tag. That way, if and when individual interfaces become popular enough to have their own tag, these questions will already be tagged with [interfaces](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interfaces).

In its current use in [What interface did Video Backup System use?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/4457/278), it is being used in a *similar* way to I have described, except asking for identification of an interface instead of asking about an interface that does not (yet?) warrant a tag. This usage is *certainly* not that of a meta tag.

(As an aside, I think that the singular [interface](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interface) is more consistent with existing general tags.)

Comment: Point taken, particularly regarding making it singular.  As it is used, it is almost an *identify-this-interface* tag, which could possibly also be useful to have.  I'm still concerned that *interfaces* per se isn't particularly useful.  Bear in mind that, with only one question, it is likely to be hit by the Roomba.

Comment: Yes, I'd also vote for a singular version, Interface(s) have always been a rather diverse topic with many issues spreading across various machines.